# bison shift/reduce conflict

Tags: parsing, bison

in the following simple grammar, on the conflict at state 4,
can 'shift' become the taken action without changing the rules ?
(I thought that by default shift was bison's preferred action)

```
%token one two three

%%

start : a;
a : X Y Z;
X : one;
Z : two | three;
Y : two | ;

%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shift is bison's preferred action, and you can see in the state output that it will shift `two` in state 4. It will still report a shift-reduce conflict, but you can take that as a warning if you like. (See `%expect`.) You'd probably be better off fixing the grammar:

```
start : a;
a : X Z | X Y Z;
X : one;
Y : two;
Z : two | three;
```

Answer (score 1):

Shift is the default, but that results in the generated parser giving an error for the input `one two` so that is probably not what you want.  Instead, follow rici's advice and fix the grammar.